# Azure Synapse - Change on "Public Network Access" destroys Workspace

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-cloud-shell, azure-synapse-analytics

After setting "Public Network Access" to "Disabled", the Synapse Workspace is not usable anymore. There's only a message "Resource provisioning failed....". Do i need to redeploy the whole Synapse workspace, or is there a shorter way to repair the workspace?

[image]

Comment: I tried with my resource and it's working fine for me. pleases share the error or deployment status.

Comment: Error code
WorkspaceUnupdatable
The workspace: ********** is not in succeeded state, and hence, cannot be updated. CurrentState = Failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error code WorkspaceUnupdatable The workspace: ********** is not in succeeded state, and hence, cannot be updated. CurrentState = Failed.

As per above error it seems that there is issue in deployment to resolve this you can follow below steps.

1. It may be causing because of **Outage in region p**lease try with another region.
2. Try with incognito mode and clear cache of your browser.

I tried in my environment (region: west us) and it is successfully executing.

[image]

If still issue persist, please raise support ticket [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) for deeper investigation.